# Reactjs submitHandler if the state is set

Tags: reactjs, state

I am new to reactjs - I've tried setting the state if checkbox get selected - and when I read the state I can see the state gets populated console.log('state' ,state) - gives {'option1': true} -- but when I do this.state.length its undefined.

Comment: Objects have no `length` property by default, maybe you're confusing it with an array?

Comment: well - how do I tell if its populated -- because it will just populate like {'option1': true, 'option2': true, 'option3': true}

Comment: Get the keys and check that array's length: `Object.keys(this.state).length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is very simple on: **State is an object** that's why length is giving `undefined`.

If you want to check how many `key-value` pairs are present then use `Object.keys`, it will return an `array` of all the keys then use length on that.

Like this:

`console.log(Object.keys(this.state).length)`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let obj = {'option1': true, 'option2': true, 'option3': true};

console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
```

Comment: cheers man - yeah usually I always work with arrays - but this is just push to the object

Comment: glad, it helped :) check the more details about `Object.keys()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I've come across it before - but rarely do I check to see if a growing object - with no array encapsulation is going on -- I always put things in an array if there are going to multiple objects like that